# Which is a better choice for shooting classroom teaching, a DSLR or a shoulder-mounted video camera**?

Tags: video, camera, dslr

I want to shoot open class videos that require  teacher's face and blackboard writing to be clear.

Which is a better choice, a **DSLR** or a **shoulder-mounted video camera**?

Comment: A good quality phone camera might fit the bill too.

Answer (score 2):

Shoulder Mounted video camera?

I think that's a little over the top, A decent 1080p or even 4k video camera (Canon, Sony, Panasonic) would give you a decent image, your main thing would be audio, you want something that would give you decent audio, a camera with a XLR input and a shotgun mic to start with and then maybe mic yourself up using a wireless kit.

Obvisouly this would all depend on budgets, time, amount of editing you want to do, maybe if you want to live stream.

Other things like decent tripod, recording media, etc will affect your budget.

Answer (score 0):

The other problem with using a DSLR is that you have a 30 minute recording limit per video.  You don't have this with a normal video camera, assuming you have space on whatever medium you are recording to.

Comment: A lot of the newer DSLR's will record over 30mins but will create a new video file.

Comment: @AdamMannPro, that's helpful information, I've been looking at some SLRs for video lately, but I'll have to take a closer look-- that would work a lot better for me!